# Is it possible for Tabulator to force time to 24Hours?

Tags: javascript, datetime, tabulator

My server data is ready with 24 hour format. 
Example: There is a time value 00:00:00 stored in sql (server), when it comes to display data into tabulator it shows 12:00:00.

```
{title: "Time", field: "time",sorter:"number", editor:"input",formatter:"datetime", 
formatterParams:{inputFormat:"hh:mm:ss", outputFormat:"hh:mm:ss", invalidPlaceholder:"Invalid Time"}
```

Is there any attribute to force formatterParams into 24Hours?

What a custom formatter should look like?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The built-in datetime formatter in Tabulator uses the moment.js library. Therefore you can use the format tokens from the [moment.js docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) to adjust the inputFormat and outputFormat for your needs.

To change the 12-hour default to 24-hour clock, simply replace "hh:mm:ss" with "HH:mm:ss".